# I'm trying to render an image using OpenGL and CuPy to ensure data stays on device without copying back to the host

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, gpu, pyopengl, pyglet

I'm trying to render an image on the GPU that goes through many pre-processing steps. The image eventually is sent to a CuPy array on the GPU and I then want to render the data within that array **without** copying data from the device back to the host. I was hoping OpenGL would be useful in this situation.

A program I have created grabs a frame from a camera buffer, performs preprocessing, renders the image to a window, and then starts the event loop over to *essentially* provide a real-time video feed. The program utilizes  OpenGL enabled PyGlet functions. However, the function I am using in pyglet `pyglet.image.ImageData`, requires the CuPy array to be converted to a bytes object ( a process that must take place on the cpu). This drastically slows down the video feed so it is no longer real-time. I would like help finding a different way to render the image without copying data to the cpu/host using Python. Perhaps by utilizing OpenGL directly rather than through PyGlet? I am also open to other libraries such as VisPy and Napari. For confidentiality purposes, I cannot show exactly what I typed up up but I have attached code that mimics what I would need. The preprocessing section within this code is essential and cannot be changed. I cannot explain why, again, for confidentiality.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
import cupy as cp
import ctypes
from cupy.cuda import MemoryPointer, UnownedMemory
from PIL import Image

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=800, height=800)
width, height = 800, 800
texture = pyglet.image.Texture.create(width, height)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(texture)

def update(dt):
    #Preprocessing Section
    pil_img = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB') #image.png is 800x800x3 (HxWxC)
    img = cp.asarray(pil_img)
    img = img.astype(cp.uint8)

    #Current block of code that renders img to an ImageData object
    img = img.tobytes() #Unfortunate conversion to bytes :/
    array = pyglet.image.ImageData(800, 800, 'RGB', img, -3 * 800)
    sprite.image = array
    sprite.scale = min(window.width/array.width, window.height/array.height)

                
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.draw()          

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Ideally, I would like help editing this program so I can try to render the image on the gpu without copying back to the cpu. "image.png" needs to be converted to a CuPy array first. I've considered converting that CuPy array to something like a gpuMat in OpenCV or another GPU array-like object, but I didn't have much success. I am very much open to other alternatives for rendering the image without device to host copying. I appreciate anyone's help with this matter!

Comment: Any luck with this? I would like to do the same.